# Peculiar behavior of font end with different evaluation result of same variable

Tags: front-end

I encountered a peculiar situation. I made a gif showing the problem.

[image]

You can see variable `eig` is different, after I created a new cell and simply reevaluated it. It seems that it substitute previous value of `bandmix` and `delt`. But I already cleared these two variables, as you can see they are all blue. What is going on here?

Comment: Nope... can't see anything.  Post code (not images).

Comment: Can we assume you've tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: @aardvark2012 No, on the contrary, I tried not to destroy this buggy state, so that if someone have some ideas to check something, I can do some following check.

Comment: Hi, @David G. Stork, but I am afraid this buggy front end problem can not be checked with copying code. Because the code is quite normal

Comment: @matheorem Is there any chance, you have a `Manipluate` or `DynamicModule` that is not shown in the screenshot?

Comment: @halirutan You are right! I have manipulate use `bandmix` and `delt` as control variables. But how would that be affect my result? It is not reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of what I believe happens. Consider a useless dynamic that sets a global variable `test`

```
Manipulate[
 test = t,
 {t, 5, 10}
 ]
```

After evaluating this, you can move the slider and `test` is set appropriately. If you use the global variable `test` in a new cell, it will, of course, have this value. Now, let's say you do `ClearAll[test]` in a cell like you did, then `test` is un-set, **but** as soon as the dynamic content get's re-evaluated, it has again the slider value.

This seems to be happening for you. You clear your `delt` and `bandmix` and can calculate the expression. But then, something triggers a re-evaluation of one of your `Manipulate`s at which point the variable get values again.

If this is the case, I hope you have learned your lesson about global variables. You can always use `DynamicModule` inside `Manipulate` to scope local variables.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solves problem.